# Showing a calculation of % of Referrals from from MD's in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that is based on data entered into a form for new patients to our clinic. One of the parts of the form is a check box that shows if a patient will need one or multiple disciples (Speech, Physcial, Occupational, Feeding Therapies) to our staff and is stored in the tables as 0 and -1.

I would like a simple way to show how many we have for each discipline unsing a subform or query that I can then refrence and then calculate it as a %

Example:

ST: 550 55%
OT: 200 20%
PT: 100 10%
FT 150 15%
Total: 1000

We just recently switched from a Google Sheet for all this data to Access. I was able to do a very very easy and simple PivotTable with Sheets, but the pivot tables in Access make me want to throw things.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MS Access. you can achieve this by using count function:

```
SELECT Count([Speech])*100/Count([patient_id]) AS TotalSpeech,
Count([Physical])*100/Count([patient_id]) AS TotalPhysical,
Count([Occupational])*100/Count([patient_id]) AS TotalOccupational,
Count([Feeding ])*100/Count([patient_id]) AS TotalFeeding
FROM tbl_patient;
```

of course you need to change the column names as per your table. the calculation is count(therapyType) * 100 divide by total patient = % of TherapyType used by patients.

Comment: Thank you!

When doing the count, won't it count every field that has a record? The ones that are not checked are 0's and the ones that are checked are -1. How do I tell it just to count the -1's?

Comment: @JosephBlake in reality you would not have any therapy fields in patient table that is a bad idea. (incase if you discontinue a therapy or add new therapy you would be forced to alter patient table). for now you can use IFF function. for a better application alter your structure, add therapy table, add therapy vs patient table and join them.